# String not equaling one another

Tags: java, string, while-loop

This program will read each phone number from the telephones.txt file and will check if it can be translated into one or more words of words.txt file. The output of the program will contain the telephone numbers and their word representatives. (assuming there are words and phones in the file)

```
while(phones.hasNext())
{
    number = phones.next();
    number = number.replace("-","");
    //Scans for next word string
    System.out.print(number + " ");
    Scanner words = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));     
    while(words.hasNext())
    {
        code = words.next();
        char[] wordChars = null;
        wordChars = code.toCharArray();
        output = "";

        for(char wordChar : wordChars)
        {
            output = output.concat(new String(convert(wordChar)));
        }

        if(number.equals(output))
        {
            end += code;
            System.out.print(code);
            if(end.isEmpty() && end !=null)
            {
                System.out.print("NONE");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();

}
}
```

Assume the words in the file are CBCNEWS , CTVNEWS and the numbers are 2251493 and 2226397
    if(number.equals(output));
            {
                System.out.println(number + " " + code);
            }
this code isn't printing only when the string number equals the string input instead it always prints. What condition do i have to make it so that it will only print when the condition is met and will also continue to look for more words

how i converted the string code was using this:

```
    public static char[] convert(char c)
{
    switch(c)
    {
        case 'A' :
        case 'B' :
        case 'C' :
            return new char[]{'2'};
        case 'D' :
        case 'E' :
        case 'F' :
            return new char[]{'3'};
        case 'G' :
        case 'H' :
        case 'I' :
            return new char[]{'4'};
        case 'J' :
        case 'K' :
        case 'L' :
            return new char[]{'5'};
        case 'M' :
        case 'N' :
        case 'O' :
            return new char[]{'6'};
        case 'P' :
        case 'R' :
        case 'S' :
            return new char[]{'7'};
        case 'T' :
        case 'U' :
        case 'V' :
            return new char[]{'8'};
        default:
            return new char[]{'9'};
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related to the problem, but I would suggest replacing your `convert` method with a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semi-colon after your if.

```
        if(number.equals(output));
        {
            System.out.println(number + " " + code);
        }
```

Should be:

```
        if(number.equals(output))
        {
            System.out.println(number + " " + code);
        }
```

Comment: wow... do you know how i would continue the loop to continue to look for more words? but thank you

Comment: Well, it loops over the phones.txt input file, and loads in the words.txt again. I don't see a problem with the loop, but if the files aren't too big, I would considering loading them into an ArrayList first and then looping over them.  What exactly do you mean?

Comment: for instance after i find a successful match, i print it out then i want to look for another match and print that out with the number so like
NUMBER + MATCH CODE (and if theres another match) + ANOTHER MATCH etc?

Comment: It looks good - you're changing the word into a number, then comparing it.  Try adding 111-1111 into the phones.txt and these two into words.txt:  AAAAAAA and BBBBBBB

Comment: One more little thing, if i scan through the loop and find no matches how would i print out "NONE"?

Comment: This would be related to when you append to the output. You could keep a string of matches, and then output after the 'words' loop is completed. If that string is empty, output NONE.  Otherwise: 111-1111: AAAAAAA, BBBBBBB, CBCBCBC

Comment: Holy crap - I meant 222-2222 in all those 111-1111 cases =)

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it still won't show "NONE" when string is null edit (i edited my program above)

Comment: It's still inside the words loop.  You want to add to end where it is... but move the system.out check outside of the while loop that it is in.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion: You may consider to change your lengthy convert method implementation by a simpler ASCII function or HashMap implementation, for example:

```
public static char[] convert(char c){
     int check = (c - 'A');
     if(check<3){ return new char[]{'2'};}
     else if(check>2 && check<6){ return new char[]{'3'};}
     else if(check>5 && check<9){ return new char[]{'4'};}
     else if(check>8 && check<12){ return new char[]{'5'};}
     else if(check>11 && check<15){ return new char[]{'6'};}
     else if(check>14 && check<19){ return new char[]{'7'};}
     else if(check>18 && check<22){ return new char[]{'8'};}
     else{ return new char[]{'9'};}
}
```

Did you miss a 'Q' for case char'7'?

Comment: I thought I remembered Q and Z not being on the phone - maybe this is region dependent?
Nope - it's changed over time:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_keypad#Layout_and_Characters

Comment: Why not just check out your mobile phone? It does appear in my windows phone 7.8 :)

Comment: A single point of reference isn't enough to determine correctness in this case ;)